# What is the best way on Python to identify if a break occurred on the last element iteration due to a condition within?

Tags: python, c, for-loop

I saw some similar questions to this but none seems to address this is specific question so I don't know if I am overlooking something since I am new to Python.

Here is the context for the question:

```
for i in range(10):
    if something_happens(i):
        break
if(something_happened_on_last_position()):
    # do something
```

From my C background, if I had a for (i=0;i<10;i++) doing the same thing with a break, then the value of i would be 10, not 9 if the break didn't occur, and 9 if it occurred on the last element. That means the method something_happened_on_last_position() could use this fact to distinguish between both events. However what I noticed on python is that i will stop on 9 even after running a successful loop without breaks.

While make a distinction between both could be as simple as adding a variable there like a flag, I never liked such usage on C. So I was curious, is there another alternative to do this or am I missing something silly here?

Do notice that I can't just use range(11) because this would run something_happens(10). It is different on C on this since '10' would fail on the condition on the for loop and would never execute something_happens(10) (since we start from index 0 here the value is 10 on both Python and C).

I used the methods just to illustrate which code chunk I was interest, they are a set of other conditions that are irrelevant for explaining the problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It works the other way:

```
for i in range(10):
    if something_happens(i):
        break
else: # no break in any position
    do whatever
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't know there was this else construction. Will accept as answer after 8 mins.

Comment: OMG. Use Python for 3 years and not know what `for` can do.

Comment: @LevLevitsky -- There's also an `else` and `finally` attached to `try`/`except` clauses.

Comment: Going to kep that in mind as well! and happy to see the question was already of use for someone else :)

Comment: @mgilson I think it's much more known. Maybe because more people read the docs on [`try-except`](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#try) than on [`for`](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#for).

Answer (score 6):

This is precisely what the `else` clause is for on `for` loops:

```
for i in range(10):
    if something_happens(i):
        break
else:
    # Never hit the break
```

The `else` clause is confusing to many, think of it as the else that goes with all those if's you executed in the loop. The `else` clause happens if the `break` never does.  More about this:  [For/else](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201110/forelse.html)

Comment: Oh wow I didn't now there was a else clause on of for Python. Thanks!